# Closing form error

Tags: c#, winforms, ado.net

I am working on my C# ADO.NET project for my school project. I have connected to an SQL Server database and can perform simple CRUD operations. I make that my app show a second Form (a reminder form) when a person in my database has a birthday on today's day, and that reminder form is displaying when I run my app, so everything works fine except that when I try to close that reminder form I get this error message:

Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'Form2'.

Here is my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

Timer timer = new Timer();
Form2 forma = new Form2();


public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var data = new BirthdayEntities();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = data.Tab_Bday.ToList();
    timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick); 
    timer.Interval = (1000) * (1);             
    timer.Enabled = true;                       
    timer.Start();                              

}




private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Boolean flag = false;
    IQueryable<Tab_Bday> name;
    using (var data2 = new BirthdayEntities())
    {
        name = (from x in data2.Tab_Bday
                select x);

        foreach (var x in name)
        {
            if (x.Datum.Day == System.DateTime.Now.Day && x.Datum.Month == System.DateTime.Now.Month)
            {
                flag = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (flag == true)
        forma.Show();

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to stop your timer:

```
if (flag == true)
{
    timer.Stop();
    forma.Show();
}
```

Right now, your `forma` instance is getting re-shown once every second (which has no effect since it's already visible until you close it), including after it's closed, which causes the exception.